# Why ajax call not hit the action method in MVC?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am working on my assignment and the ajax call not hit the action method. I debugged and check it not reach the action method.Here is my code.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/Admin/Workflow/Save?Id=" + Id + "&template=" + template,
            success: function() {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(xhr) {

                alert("Data not saved");
            }
```

It show the data not saved. It worked fine but i don't know what happen.

Here is my actin method

```
public JsonResult Save(int Id, int template, List<Sequence> data)
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser console?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: if it wasn't hitting it would be a 404. 500 is a server error.

Comment: That means your controller method is throwing an exception. Debug your code!

Comment: Manually send a POST request using something like Postman to the URL with the parameters. You can then see the error. It's probably that you are not passing the right parameters types, e.g. passing a `string` instead of an `int`

Comment: @StephenMuecke He mentioned he debugged it but it was not hitting his `ActionMethod`

Comment: @jamie rees company id and template id are recived as int and in JS file i get value from dropdown list

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error)  means it is hitting the method. If its not executing, it could be because of an attribute (e.g `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`)

Comment: @Hiba You need to find out the reason behind the HTTP 500 error.

Comment: can you show us your action method

Comment: I have added a picture.Please see it

Comment: public JsonResult SaveCopyWorkflow(int companyId, int templateId, List<WfTaskTemplateSequence> data)

Comment: why are you passing querystring and data paramter in ajax ?

Comment: @Hiba, Use you developer tools to debug (inspect the response in the Network tab to see the details of the error)

Comment: I need this parameters for some purpose

Comment: @Hiba, You do NOT need the parameter and it should not be there (you not passing it a value so its pointless and should be removed) but that's not the cause of your problem.

Comment: company id and template id are global

Comment: You need to add your controller action to your question (including attributes) if you want people to help.

Comment: Added the action method

Comment: Add an HttpPost attribute to your action method. Also, remove the contentType and data parameters in your ajax call, those cause me grief sometimes and jQuery does a pretty good job of automatically setting those for you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. Everything was fine. The issue was  the data is not converted correctly in JSON. I checked my json, there is a problem in array (obj) that i stringfy in json. So i corrected the objTaskTemplate.It works fine now